# youtube-dl with ytsearchdate return only 20 results

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I am trying extracting information from youtube using `youtube-dl` with the `ytsearchdate` function.

The code below should extract information from 25 pages, but is extracting only 20.

```
import youtube_dl
ydl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({"ignoreerrors": True})
results = ydl.extract_info("ytsearchdate25:\"stackoverflow\"", download=False)

Result logs
 
[youtube:search:date] query ""stackoverflow"": Downloading page 1
[download] Downloading playlist: "stackoverflow"
[youtube:search:date] playlist "stackoverflow": Collected 20 video ids (downloading 20 of them)
[download] Downloading video 1 of 20
[youtube] bRJirSOWYts: Downloading webpage
[youtube] bRJirSOWYts: Downloading js player e49bfb00
[youtube] bRJirSOWYts: Downloading js player e49bfb00
[youtube] bRJirSOWYts: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Downloading video 2 of 20
[youtube] RiZBaBx945M: Downloading webpage
[youtube] RiZBaBx945M: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Downloading video 3 of 20
[youtube] cFCW6VX0y74: Downloading webpage
[download] Downloading video 4 of 20
[youtube] k7JlWpd0E6E: Downloading webpage
[youtube] k7JlWpd0E6E: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Downloading video 5 of 20
[youtube] 8HtwyVtvPso: Downloading webpage
[youtube] 8HtwyVtvPso: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Downloading video 6 of 20
[youtube] wRJ4JMQbx7Q: Downloading webpage
[youtube] wRJ4JMQbx7Q: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Downloading video 7 of 20
[youtube] LwYQ8zTK1h8: Downloading webpage
[youtube] LwYQ8zTK1h8: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Downloading video 8 of 20
[youtube] Laz06nxKw9Y: Downloading webpage
[youtube] Laz06nxKw9Y: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Downloading video 9 of 20
[youtube] PGV-F-rOGKQ: Downloading webpage
[youtube] PGV-F-rOGKQ: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Downloading video 10 of 20
[youtube] 7dPH-9IzC0c: Downloading webpage
[youtube] 7dPH-9IzC0c: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Downloading video 11 of 20
[youtube] 1bJMdstVQmQ: Downloading webpage
[youtube] 1bJMdstVQmQ: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Downloading video 12 of 20
[youtube] S-2Xyobgvx8: Downloading webpage
[youtube] S-2Xyobgvx8: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Downloading video 13 of 20
[youtube] RHwDEWR9EdY: Downloading webpage
[youtube] RHwDEWR9EdY: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Downloading video 14 of 20
[youtube] vokX_8d-i30: Downloading webpage
[youtube] vokX_8d-i30: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Downloading video 15 of 20
[youtube] NbXoYJTf47A: Downloading webpage
[youtube] NbXoYJTf47A: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Downloading video 16 of 20
[youtube] OVj2zEx11gw: Downloading webpage
[youtube] OVj2zEx11gw: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Downloading video 17 of 20
[youtube] yPKL12JjzIA: Downloading webpage
[youtube] yPKL12JjzIA: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Downloading video 18 of 20
[youtube] a778gAKZ-uM: Downloading webpage
[youtube] a778gAKZ-uM: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Downloading video 19 of 20
[youtube] Y3QdpImsHs4: Downloading webpage
[youtube] Y3QdpImsHs4: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Downloading video 20 of 20
[youtube] FB-zyW3TI0I: Downloading webpage
[youtube] FB-zyW3TI0I: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Finished downloading playlist: "stackoverflow"
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `ytsearchdate25:` wrong here.
If you use `ytsearch` + some `n` as `25` it will give you 25 results.
If you use `ytsearchdate` you basically use `ytsearch:date:`.
So actually your query was this `ytsearch:date25:` - this means you get all videos that are uploaded on some 25th of a month (?)
My guess is ytsearch default return value is 20 videos (probably set by youtube itself).

Ultimately to get what you want is either to use `ytsearch25:` which will return 25 results or `ytsearch25:date25:` which will return 25 results of the 25th day.  I am not exactly sure how date is interpreted - 25 days earlier from current date or last 25th of a month or something completely else.

Comment: It would be great to have the use of ytsearchdate cleared in the documentation. What does ytsearchdate mean? How to search the most recent 10 videos? Or all the videos after a specific date?